# Convert a set of managed objects to a dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary, nsmanagedobject, nsset

I have a `NSSet` (e.g. "fruits") which consists of `NSManagedObjects` and is created by using the following filtering code:

```
NSSet *fruits = [self.allFruits filteredSetUsingPredicate:
                         [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"quantity > 10"];
```

Each of the fruits has the following properties (attributes): `name` (e.g.: apple, orange, banana), `color` (red, yellow, green) and `quantity` (100, 20, 10).

What would be the most efficient way to create a `NSDictionary` out of this `NSSet` which contains the `name`s of the fruits as the keys and the `quantities` as the objects (e.g. key:object: apple: 100 orange: 20)?

This is how this could be done using block enumeration:

```
__block NSMutableDictionary *fruitsAndColors = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[fruits enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id fruit, BOOL *stop) {
      [fruitsAndColors setObject:fruit.color forKey:fruit.name];
}];
```

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish the same?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a custom NSManagedObject subclass with a method that writes writes each object out to a dictionary with the keys and values that you want.

Then you can enumerate your NSSet and call this method on each object to create a collection of dictionaries.

I'm only giving you a general idea because you've asked a general question. If you try and write the code you can come back with any further problems that you face.

Answer (score 3):

It's fast and easy way.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:ManagedObjectItems.count];
[[ManagedObjectItems allObjects] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    Diary_item_food *food = obj;
    NSArray *keys = [[[food entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
    NSDictionary *dict = [obj dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
    [array addObject:dict];
}];
```